# Python zip adds multiple duplicates files in final archive

Tags: python, zip

Problem:
Suppose i am writing 20 small pdf files in zip, then the zip size is around 400 MB whereas the total size of those 20 files is only 4 MB. After opening the created zip file there are only 20 files but when i perform recovery operation on that zip file there comes a lot of pdf duplicates to the files i have archived, i have no idea why. The files are stored in s3 and zip is created in s3 as well, when i do everything localy it works fine. Follwoing is the code fragment which i am using

```
with process_obj.archive_file.storage.open(process_obj.archive_file.name, 'wb') as archive_file:
        # Create a zip archive
        with zipfile.ZipFile(archive_file, mode='w', compression=zipfile.ZIP_DEFATED) as zip_file:
            # Write excel file in zip
            process_obj.excel_file.save(download_excel_util.get_excel_filename(), temp_workbook)
            zip_file.writestr(
                download_excel_util.get_excel_filename(),
                process_obj.excel_file.read()
            )
            process_obj.added_file_count += 1
            process_obj.save()

            for file in files:
                zip_file.writestr(u'{}{}'.format(u'Profiles/', u'{}.pdf'.format(resume.get_file_name())), file.read())
                # Update `added_file_count` in process object
                process_obj.added_file_count += 1
                process_obj.save()
```

Comment: I'm not sure what your `process_obj` is, but do you really need to call `.save()` on it twenty times?  The zip file isn't even in a consistent state during any of those times, because it's still open for writing.

Comment: This code snippet if from a asynchronous task so by saving added_file_count shows it's progress.
Porcess object conatins the archive file as one of it's field, and i am adding other files to the archive
BTW I am using python2.7